# Entity Framework's DBContext doesn't update database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create a row for a database which I manage.
I have tried to build a code as an example to check if it's working, but it doesn't update the database:

```
PolicyList = await LoadPolicy(); //Loads Policy List
            tblPolicy tbl = new tblPolicy(); //Creates a new policy entity
            tbl.polID = 5; //Sets ID to 5
            tbl.polName = "Ryder"; //Sets name
            mdbe.tblPolicies.Add(tbl); //Adds to the dbcontext object
            mdbe.Entry(tbl).State = EntityState.Added; //Changes the state to "Added"
            await mdbe.SaveChangesAsync(); //Saves changes
```

It doesn't work whether I'm using an Asynchronous method or not, and the same goes with the EntityState.Added.
How can I save the changes?

```
private async Task<List<tblPolicy>> LoadPolicy()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => mdbe.tblPolicies.ToList());
    }
```

mdbe definition:

```
    EntryDBEntities mdbe = new EntryDBEntities();
```

the POCO class of entryDBentities:

```
public partial class EntryDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public EntryDBEntities()
        : base("name=EntryDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<tblEntry> tblEntries { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tblEntryPolicy> tblEntryPolicies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<tblPolicy> tblPolicies { get; set; }
}
```

[Mapping of the entity framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltVL4.png)

Comment: please post complete source code .

Comment: Which database does not get updated? I mean how do you verify the issue?

Comment: Does it throw an exception ?

Comment: First line of code looks strange and you don't need `mdbe.Entry(tbl).State = EntityState.Added; //Changes the state to "Added"`.  Try SaveChanges() instead of SaveChangesAsync(). If that works you may have an async-issue in your code.

Comment: Can you post the `LoadPolicy()` code as well as where your `mdbe` is defined?

Comment: @Mahdi the table tblPolicy doesn't update. I check my database every time.

Comment: @Mats391updated it

Comment: @Adrien didn't throw any exceptions

Comment: @Marc told you. it doesn't work

Comment: I am referring to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543474/entity-framework-code-first-default-database-location. So are you sure you are checking the db which your code works with? Just to make sure.

Comment: What is the reason for this? `return await Task.Run(() => mdbe.tblPolicies.ToList());` Why not `await mdbe.tblPolicies.ToListAsync()` ? Actually just remove the whole method and move it inline.

Comment: @Igor it's to load the policy list for something else that will occur afterwards.

Comment: @Mahdi I checked it
I'm just checking if the DB updates

Comment: As @Igor suggested, try using ToListAsync() instead ToList() and return Task<IEnumerable<tblPolicy>> instead a list.

Comment: It`s unclear how you create your context imstance tbl, it will be good to show that code as well

Comment: You can also attach a logger that will write to the console to see what EF does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @igor Please check my comment on your answer

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the unecessary / extranious parts of your code and create an MVE([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to test with.

```
using(EntryDBEntities mdbe = new EntryDBEntities())
{
  // PolicyList = await LoadPolicy(); // do not include this, it has nothing to do with adding a new entity based on the code you have shown
  tblPolicy tbl = new tblPolicy(); //Creates a new policy entity
  tbl.polID = 5; //Sets ID to 5
  tbl.polName = "Ryder"; //Sets name
  mdbe.tblPolicies.Add(tbl); //Adds to the dbcontext object
  await mdbe.SaveChangesAsync(); //Saves changes
}
```

The above fragment should add a new `tblPolicy` to the underlying database and is the bare minimum required code to do so.

If this "does not work" please provide the following:

1. How does it not work? If an Exception is thrown please provide all of the Exception's properties (stacktrace, message, type, and same for inner exceptions).
2. If you do not see a result please describe how you are checking the store that your entity was not created/added? It could be as simple as you overridding an .mdf file on a local db when you execute your application from VS.
3. Include the complete mapping for entity `tblPolicy`

Comment: It just doesn't update my database, and it doesn't throw any exception.
I'm checking it by watching the data on the database, and I see that it stays the same. I have updated the mapping in the question